# Why overridden `controller.$render` is not getting called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have a look at this code @ [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDQEkgglpOZFUoeBjgKt?p=preview). In the `link` function of `directive`, `controller.$render()` was called which worked fine. Problem is when I override `controller.$render` function then it does not run. `console.log('overridden $render function called');` does not appear in the console.

`script.js` is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, controller) {
            if (!controller) {
                console.log("controller of ngModel not found");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("controller of ngModel found");
                controller.$setViewValue('qwerty');
                //controller.$render();
                controller.$render = function(){
                  console.log('overridden $render function called');  
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content </div>


        <input test type="text" ng-model="name" >

        <h1>name: {{name}}</h1>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to call `controller.$render();` and ofcourse after `controller.$render = function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `controller.$render()` right after you override it:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, controller) {
            if (!controller) {
                console.log("controller of ngModel not found");
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("controller of ngModel found");
                controller.$setViewValue('qwerty');
                //controller.$render();
                controller.$render = function(){
                  console.log('overridden $render function called');  
                }
                controller.$render();
            }
        }
    };
});
```